# Object attributes combination query Mongodb Repository

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I am trying to query based on Object attributes combination in MongoDB:

My Object looks like:

```
@Getter
@Setter
class Person {
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private Address address;
}
```

Address entity looks like:

```
@Getter
@Setter
class Address {
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private String postal;
    private String country;
}
```

Assume that above classes are also annotated with necessary attributes required for MongoDB collections.

Now when I am about to query from a PersonRepo interface that extends MongoRepository, as:

```
public interface PersonRepo extends MongoRepository<Person, String> {
    
}
```

The objective is to fetch all result-set where Address matches any combination of city, state, postal or country. For example, I want to fetch all results where city=XYZCity, state = ABCState, Postal might not be provided and country might be DEFCountry.

***Address can be in any combination and whatever combination matches, the result-set could be produced.***

Comment: Must all provided values match? Or just at least one?

Comment: All provided values.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add optional query parameter using spring data mongodb repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49936463/add-optional-query-parameter-using-spring-data-mongodb-repository)